# Typescript error in react native using react navigation

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a typescript error in React Native that I can't figure out

```
const handleLearningPathRedirect = (item: any) => {
    const routeParams: any = {
        props: item,
    };

    navigation.navigate(navigationString.LearningPath, routeParams);
};
```

Argument of type '[string, any]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

I would rather not quick fix and disable eslint error and anything I have tried results in the same error

```
interface RouteParams {
  props: any; 
}

const handleLearningPathRedirect = (item: any) => {
  const routeParams: RouteParams = {
    props: item,
  };

  navigation.navigate('LearningPath', routeParams);
};
```

Comment: could you console.log whatever is in navigationString.LearningPath. Check that it's actually a string. If not, track back and find out why.

Comment: Can you make it clear: where the error appear?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/.